# In android when i try to run my project it fails?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

In android when i try to run my project it says 'No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'?
I did the following steps but nothing changed.Why is that?
-->open android SDK manager,make sure that Android Support Library is installed..

-->After that the AppCompat Can be found at

android-sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat
-->You need to reference this AppCompat in your android project.

-->Import the library to eclipse. -->Right click on your android project. Goto Properties. goto andorid. Click Add Library and reference the same. -->Clean and Rebuild your project

Comment: What error its showing now ?

Comment: The same error which says No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.Nothing is changed after all of the above steps?why is that?

Comment: Have you copied your AppCompat Library into your workspacE?

Comment: yes.I have copied it.

Comment: What is your minimum sdk ?Please post screenshot with your error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do:

- **File->Import (android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7).**
- Choose  **"appcompat" Project-> properties->Android**.
- In the section library **"Add"** and choose "**appCompat**" That is all!